# How to show button dropdown with keyboard in Intellij Idea (OS X)

Tags: macos, intellij-idea

I know that I can press Commit button (right bottom corner) by using Alt+I but my question is: how to show dropdown (using only Macbook Pro keyboard) that is shown after you press small arrow inside Commit button ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a control + Alt + i and then use the up/down arrows to choose the entry from the dropdown.

Comment: Yep, tried it, doesn't work for some reason. I'm on Intellij 2016, El Capitan

Comment: Ok got it, Magnet captured Ctrl+Alt+I shortcut